Does $\int_a^b g^2=0 $ imply $\int_a^b fg=0$?
I am trying to prove the Cauchy Schwarz inequality for integrable functions, which is as follows:

(Cauchy-Schwarz): If $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$, then $$\left(\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}g^{2}\right)\ge\left(\int_{a}^{b}fg \right)^{2} $$

I have proved it for the case when $\int_a^bg^2>0$. For the other case, it will be true iff $$\int_a^bg^2=0\implies \int_a^bfg=0\qquad \text{ for every integrable $f$}$$ which I am having difficulty in proving. Any hints would be appreciated.

What does $\int_a^b g^2=0$ tell you about $g$?

@JonasLenz $g(x)=0$ at every point of continuity(of which there are infinitely many)  I think

Yeah, but's even more than infinitely many. When talking about integration, the "number" of points is maybe not the important thing but rather the size of this set.

@JonasLenz I am unfortunately unfamiliar with cardinality and measure of infinite sets. Is there a more elementary argument to deduce this?

Are you talking about integrals in the sense of Riemann or Lebesgue?

@JonasLenz I am using Darboux's definition of the integral to be precise

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3713481/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1781275/42969.

We have $|fg|\le af^2+a^{-1}g^2$ for any $a>0.$ Thus $$\left |\int fg\right |\le\int |fg|\le a\int f^2+a^{-1}\int g^2$$ If $\int g^2=0$ then  taking the limit $a\to 0^+$ gives $\int fg =0.$

I forgot the constant ${1\over 2}.$ Should be $ |fg|\le {1\over 2}[af^2+a^{-1}g^2].$ By the way the notion of the integral does not matter: Riemann, Lebesgue or Riemann-Stieltjes.

@RyszardSzwarc What you suggest does seem to work; as a side note, could you explain how you arrived at this line of reasoning? and is there a more direct way to deduce the result?

The inequality is frequently  used to prove the C-S one by finding the minimum of RHS with respect to $a.$
